# Button action-Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am practicing from the book Hello,Android ed3.There is an example code on creating an action button to display 'About' the game.I have edited all the necessary xml files.I am getting error in the following code.logcat is showing nullpointer exception in line 10: about.Button.setClickListener(this).Please help.Also i have been unable to understand 'this' parameter.Any hep?

```
public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      // Set up click listeners for all the button
      View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
      aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
          switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.about_button:
             Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
             startActivity(i);
             break;
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you dont have "about_button" button in the xml file. Did you give the same name for the button in xml?

Comment: make sure that your main.xml is the one with the button in it or change it to the actual layout file being used.

Comment: post your xml file here.. Are you still getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   // Set up click listeners for all the button
   Button aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about_button);
  aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      if(v == aboutButton){
         Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
         startActivity(i);
         break;
}
```

Try this one... just changed 2-3 lines...

Comment: Copied the code as it is.Still shows same error.Please explain what is 'this' parameter here?